# Travel between Schengen countries few days before visa expiry

Tags: visas, schengen

I have Danish residence permit on student visa which will expire on 31 July 2017. I want to visit Poland on 26 or 27 July.

Can I enter another Schengen country just few days before my visa expires?

Comment: Is your residence permit expiring, or only the visa?

Comment: Expiring both visa and residence card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can travel freely within the Schengen area as long as your permit is valid.  You will generally need to leave the Schengen area on or before the permit's expiration date, or make arrangements for a new permit or visa.